# C++ Universal Windows app only works when VS2015 project on install drive

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

***Steps to rep:***

1. Create a new, blank, UWP, VC++ app project (File --> New -->  Project --> Visual C++ --> Windows --> Universal --> Blank App)
2. Store the project on D:\  *(Visual Studio is installed on C:)*
3. Hit F5 to build and run the app (I'm running in Debug, x64)

***Error:***

[image: Error image]

4. Now repeat the process but this time store the project on C:.
*Everything works just fine.*

**How do I configure Visual Studio to let me run projects stored on a drive different than the drive on which VS is installed?**

***Specs:***

- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
- Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
- Microsoft .NET Framework
- Version 4.6.01038
- Windows 10 (fully patched).

Comment: This may not be relevant, but just to make sure: is your D drive removable?

Comment: No.  I have a laptop with an SSD (C:) and a 1TB platter drive (D:)

Comment: [This post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/12/03/windows-10-build-10586-sdk-breakdown/) on what's new in build 10586 sates that it is now possible to install apps on a secondary drive. I assume that implies it just wasn't possible before.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Yep.  I agree with you.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten I updated the SDK.  The problem remains.  I'm just going to work off he SSD when I'm actively working on a project.  I'm don't use UWP enough to make it worth spending too much time on this issue.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Same issue with C# Universal Apps. Followed a lot of threads here and on MS support about "The app didn't start" error with blind guesses and mis-advice from MS support, until finally found advice to try the project on the C drive. Bingo, that works. Tried fresh projects from scratch, same. Only run on C drive. If however I change the target to run the app on a Win 10 Emulator it works fine from my data drive (E drive in my case, standard hard disc. C is an SSD).

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment on the question, I have the same issue. I'm not sure this counts as an answer as it's a workaround, but this at least for a C# Universal project...

Go to the project properties for the app and set the **Output path** to a location on C drive.

e.g. **C:\dev\MyTestApp\bin\x86\Debug**

(for Debug build. Likewise substitute x64 for x86 for 64bit etc)

It will build and run with the output on C drive but the project remains on the other drive.

Not an ideal solution, but avoids the error.